# android load RecyclerView when a RecyclerView reachs ends

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have an Endless `RecyclerView` with library [PullLoadView](https://github.com/tosslife/PullLoadView/)

this `RecyclerView` is fill the layout, I want to when this `RecyclerView` load all its items and reach the end of end, I load another `RecyclerView` at bottom of it, which has its own adapter and row layout and continue .

something like this application I need :

first `RecyclerView`:

[image: first recyclerView]

first `RecyclerView` reaches end and new `RecyclerView` show up

[image: first recyclerView reaches end and new recyclerView show up]

new `RecyclerView` continue the first `RecyclerView` in full layour screen

[image: new recyclerView continue the first recyclerView in full layour screen]

xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_search"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvTwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to use Recyclerview only for the bottom view as well? Can you use ListView for the bottom one?

Comment: You should combine these 2 and make use of `viewtype` see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

Comment: I don't want the exact thing like images above, I just need the solution to make two match_parent recyclerViews after each other

Comment: @MohammadHadi post your xml code. Btw you can achieve this using NestedScrollView. By default nestedscrollview expand all views in it

Comment: @Ankush Bist the problem is I don't know how my xml would look like , but I edit my question and copy xml with the view inside

Comment: @MohammadHadi try with my answer posted below. Nested scrollview will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `xml` source with the below source

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: it works perfect, but because one of my RecyclerViews is Endless with library it has some problems with this solution, but I will fix it, thank you for help

Comment: in this solution does all the row of RecyclerView load at once? is it optimal?

Comment: not optimal. But yes this will display the api result and expand the recycler view at once. But in case of load more in recycler view this the onScroll load more data of recycler will also called

Comment: I think I should customize the last row of first RecyclerView and put another RecyclerView with it's own adapter inside it, and load it , when the last data gotten from server in first RecyclerView. but I don't know how to code it right

Comment: probably you have to do this like. Add a button view more or load more which will redirect you too further activity/fragment what ever you found best with you requirement and display only few elements in first page where these 2 recyclerviews are needed to display. This is better idea and also user friendly otherwise user will never gonna to know that you have some another recycler view at the bottom like if your first recyclerView contains 1000's of data.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a NestedScrollView with a vertically oriented LinearLayout and Disable their scrolling by setting their linearlayout manager like this.

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean canScrollVertically() {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: how my xml would looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView as your bottom View and in your ListView header put RecycerView

list_sample.xml (This is your main layout for activity set content)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

header_recycler.xml(List view header layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

item_header.xml(items for header's list i.e. recyclerview one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_header_regular"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FF2255" />


</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml (List view's item)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

HeaderRecyclerView.java  (RecyclerView adapter)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class HeaderRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HeaderRecyclerView.HeaderHolder> {
    private final Context context;
    private List<String> items;

    public HeaderRecyclerView(List<String> items, Context context) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public HeaderHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent, false);
        return new HeaderHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HeaderHolder holder, int position) {
        String item = items.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (items == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return items.size();
    }

    class HeaderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;

        HeaderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_header_regular);
        }
    }
}
```

BottomListAdapter.java (ListView adapter)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BottomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public BottomListAdapter(List<String> items, Context context) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        TextView txtView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
            txtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(txtView));
        } else {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            txtView = viewHolder.txtView;
        }

        String string = getItem(i);
        txtView.setText(string);

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        public final TextView txtView;

        public ViewHolder(TextView txtView) {
            this.txtView = txtView;
        }
    }

}
```

In Your onCreate use the below to initialize as follwing

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_sample);

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_recycler, null);

        RecyclerView headerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_header);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            strings.add(i + "");
        }

        headerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        headerList.setAdapter(new HeaderRecyclerView(strings, this));

        listView.addHeaderView(view);
        listView.setAdapter(new BottomListAdapter(strings, this));
```

Comment: I don't get it, how the xml code would looks like? thanks

Comment: In you xml you would only have ListView give me a minute i will fabricate code and post here.